# 404 error issue with Path() pattern

Tags: django, django-urls

```
path('add', views.TopicCreate.as_view(), name='add-topic')
]
```

When i try to run it (by entering http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/add), it gives me 404 error saying it didn't match any of the patterns. even though it says that there's matching url pattern right there.

```
home/ [name='index']
home/ <int:topic_id> [name='details']
home/ add [name='topic-add']
admin/

The current path, home/add/, didn't match any of these.
```

The weird thing is, the link works when i try it in Mozilla and Google Incognito. Doesn't work on IE (private window or not) and normal Chrome.

full urls.py :

```
app_name = "home"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('<int:topic_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('add', views.TopicCreate.as_view(), name='topic-add')
    ]
```

Comment: You need to provide full error description. Show entire `urls.py` file, show url you enter in your browser.

Comment: Is the name switched around? 'topic-add' and 'add-topic'?

Comment: @gonczor in a moment.

Comment: @leelum1 i'm not referencing url by name anywhere right now, could that still cause an error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#append-slash) set to `False` in your settings or you don't have `CommonMiddleware` in your middlewares.

The reason behind the ERROR 404 is that your url does not end in a slash `home/add` but you are visiting the path with a slash `home/add/`. This will not raise an HTTP_ERROR if you have included [CommomMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware), or set `APPEND_SLASH` to True in your settings.

Bear in mind that this will have some effects like it will issue a redirect, etc.  Please see the documentation in the link above for more information.

If you don't want to set `APPEND_SLASH`, you can update your urls and add a slash at the end:

```
path('add/', views.TopicCreate.as_view(), name='add-topic')
```